# Blank page when selecting "Test Plan"

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm unable to create a test plan on Azure DevOps. A blank page shows up when I select the "Test Plan" option.

Comment: Did you try logging off / on? Have you tried on a different device? What region is your organization created? I just created a new organization and the "Test Plans" loads properly.

Comment: Do you mean you get blank page when you click `Test Plan` tab? Is there any error message? Could you share a screenshot and capture a fiddler trace (https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)?

Comment: As per Sajeetharan's answer, if you don't have a Test license, DevOps will try to show a 'Test Hub' page trying to upsell you.
However my Ad Blocker didn't like this and also got a blank page with js errors, instead.

Answer (score 1):

Users with Basic license can't create a Test plan and thus you face this issue. VS Dev Essentials subscription doesn't include Basic + Test Plans license. Please go to Billing page, check whether your organization have brought [`Basic+ Test`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops) Plan.